# Node.js read file from disk

Tags: node.js

I want to write NP music in discord status. Google Play Music Desktop Player has a playback.json file, I need to check this file in my node.js and change music in discord status. At this moment I have this code for checking this file

```
const fs = require(`fs`)

var song = [];

check();

function check() {
    fs.readFile("C:\\Users\\lensh\\AppData\\Roaming\\Google Play Music Desktop Player\\json_store\\playback.json", (err, data) => {
        let playback = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(`Checking...`)
        if(playback.playing !== `true`) return setTimeout(() => {check()}, 10000), console.log(`IDLE.`), idle();
        else {
            if(song.includes(playback.song.title)) return setTimeout(() => {check();}, 10000), console.log(`Waiting...`), console.log(song), console.log(playback.song.title);
            else {
                song.splice(0, song.length);
                song.push(playback.song.title);
                status(playback.song.artist, playback.song.title);
                setTimeout(() => {check();}, 15000)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is that node.js reads the file only on the startup, then node.js didn`t check this file for any changes. How to solve this problem?

P.S. Sry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do manually. You can use the node.js watch file API and load the file on change.

```
const fs = require("fs")
let lastUpdated = new Date()
fs.watchFile("./test.json", (curr, prev) => {
  if(curr.mtime.getTime() - lastUpdated.getTime() > 2 *1000) { // after 2 min
    // DO something here
    console.log(`the current mtime is: ${curr.mtime}`);
    lastUpdated = curr.mtime
  }
})
```

**Ref:** https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

Comment: The file changes every second because the programm write current song time in this file

Comment: yes then u skip for time.. like counter or seconds, Basic logic to skip

Answer (score 0):

You may need to watch the file change and let's your function run.

https://thisdavej.com/how-to-watch-for-files-changes-in-node-js/